# IntelliJ Idea IDE interpreting/reading/processing code slow (Thread.sleep() )

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, intellij-idea

It's a bit hard to explain. I did some googling on the matter and didn't find anything that seemed like it would help. Now, I don't know if it's my computer that might be limiting the IDE, (6gb ram, AMD A10-5745M APU 2.10GHz, Windows 8 64 bit, it seems the max the IDE can use at the moment is 495M, although it's never gone past 70M) I shall share my code before explaining the problem further: Edit: Oh, and to add on, this is basically all the code i've written, so this method isn't in some huge project, it's basically the only thing i've written so far.

```
public void readText(String text){
      String textArray[]= new String[text.length()];
        for(int b = 0; b <text.length(); b++){
            String countText = text;
            textArray[b] = countText.substring(b,b+1);
        }

        for(int countPrint = 0; countPrint < textArray.length; countPrint++){
            System.out.print(textArray[countPrint]);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically, what my method does is, it reads text at a delayed interval, character by character. So if I were to call `readText("Hello");` it would print `H`(wait 50 ms)`e`(wait 50 ms)`l`(etc.) and so and and so forth, so it would look like someone was typing. (I was going to use timers, but through googling and from this site, I found that `Thread.sleep(number)` was much easier to setup, and took up less space)

Now that I've explained everything, the problem is that it doesn't quite display it character by character, once I get down to the shorter milliseconds, like 50. I pick, say, 800ms and it reads each character fine, and it spits them out almost 1 per second. but the quicker it gets, the more it clumps. Say I have the phrase "Hello, my dog is yellow and my lawn is pink". If it were to print that with `Thread.sleep(50)` like the code is, it would (instead of printing each character individually (albeit very quickly)) print in chunks `chunk1(Hel) chunk2(lo, my) chunk3(dog i) chunk4(s yello)` and so on. Now, I know I've narrowed it down to the IDE, because when I ran the same code in Eclipse, it printed almost perfectly (It printed chunks sometimes, but when it did, it was only 2 characters, not 5 or 6 like with Jidea) I didn't try any faster speeds with Eclipse, but the 50ms didn't seem to bother it all too much, certainly ran it much more precisely than the former. Any ideas on why it wouldn't print it in "real-time" per-se?

Comment: Could it be the case that Idea is not running the code in a separate VM? BTW, I'd test such things from the command line to exclude external influences as much as possible. Still, depending on the load of your machine, your sleep() calls give the OS the opportunity to page out the JVM running this code.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about running the .java from the command line, but I couldn't seem to get it to work, something about the .class not existing, even though I made sure they were in the same folder. I probably need to redo my environment variables or whatever, although when I run the... I can't remember what command it is, but it returns your version of java and whatnot, that works perfectly fine.

Comment: Ok, running it from the command line, it runs perfectly fine with no clumps at all, each character one at a time. I guess it's just how the ide prints the characters, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess on your problem is that is due to the buffering of output.

`System.out` is buffered (i.e. it will not necessarily write to the terminal straight-away when you call print, but may choose to delay writing, or batch multiple *print* calls into one console write).

You could try issuing a `flush` ( i.e. `System.out.flush()`) after each character and see if that helps, but it might not be that simple.

I'd be hesitant about worrying too much about how quickly terminal I/O happens inside an IDE. There's lots of things that can play a part in that, and it's typically not something you need to care about. If you do care, then you'd be better running from the command-line than from inside the IDE.

Comment: OP also told that "i've narrowed it down to the IDE, because when I ran the same code in Eclipse, it printed almost perfectly"

Comment: @eis Yes they did, but I'm not sure what point you're trying to make, or how it changes my answer.

Comment: that buffering of System.out *by default* should not be the one to blame, but buffering Idea does. System.out is buffered even if you use command line, but that didn't show the same problem, apparently, so just buffering doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: The OP hasn't indicated that they ever tried it on the command line, so the only information we have is that the output behaved differently on two different IDEs that have very different architectures and entirely different output consoles. It is entirely reasonable to believe that Idea's console buffers `System.out` differently to the Eclipse console - the JRE does not *require* any particular behaviour. The OP is expecting System.out to be unbuffered just because one IDE acts that way. That is his mistake. System.out can be buffered, so if you want immediate  output, then call `flush`.

Comment: I'm going to try running my program and see how it runs from the command line, then i'll get back to you on that. if it's still having problems in the command line, then i'll try flushing System.out in the for loop and see if that helps.

Comment: Ok, I ran it from the command line and it ran perfectly, so I guess it's just how the IDEs print the code? Either way, works perfectly fine in the command line. In the IDE, i'm going to try the flush to see if that fixes the problem, if it doesn't, then oh well, i'll just live with it, only a slight annoyance.